# How can I join two tables using Eloquent?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

My database structure:

```
widgets.id | widgets.site_id
sites.id   | sites.user_id
users.id
```

A widget belongs to a website, a website belongs to an user. User can create many websites, and many widgets under a website.

What I need to do is:

```
\Widget::with('site')->where('site.user_id', Auth::id()->get();
```

However, that doesn't work. So I tried this:

```
\Widget::join('sites', 'widgets.site_id', '=', 'sites.id')->where('user_id', Auth::id())->get());
```

This one works, but then I cannot access `widget.id`, since `sites.id` overrides the `id` attribute. (Also I don't like using Fluent features so would like to do it in pure Eloquent.)

Basically, how can do the following query: "Select all the widgets that belongs this user."

As a result, I would like to use the following in result. (pseudo)

```
{{ $widget->id }} // 1
{{ $widget->site->id }} // 3
{{ $widget->site->user->username }} // Aristona
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `SELECT` only widgets table when you use `join`:

```
\Widget::join('sites', 'widgets.site_id', '=', 'sites.id')
  ->where('user_id', Auth::id())
  ->with('site.user')
  ->select('widgets.*')->get();
  // or simply:
  // ->get(['widgets.*']);
```

You can also do it without manually joining the table:

```
$userId = Auth::id();
\Widget::whereHas('site', function ($q) use ($userId) {
    $q->where('user_id', $userId);
})->with('site.user')->get();
```

I used `with` to eager load the relations on your widgets. Otherwise you would end up with n+1 queries issue.

Comment: You're a savior. I just saw you've helped me plently of times on SO, so thank you once again! :)

Comment: No probs, eloquent is my thing.